# iPhone programming post data

Tags: iphone, sdk3.0

i am trying to post data from iPhone to PHP web server. Here is my following code:

```
NSString * fname = @"Brain.";
 NSString * location = @"Germany";

 NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fname=Test&location=Germany"];

 NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://frisbee.brianpagan.net/upload.php"]];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [request setHTTPBody:postData];

 NSError *error;
 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
 NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(data);


    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

The debugger windows output:

```
Session started at 2010-03-12 00:03:04 +0100.]
2010-03-12 00:03:05.871 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e061f0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x28e4da 0x23fe 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:05.873 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e07470 of class NSConcreteMutableData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x2c7a22 0x2428 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:05.873 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e07030 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x28e4da 0x2470 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:05.874 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e07710 of class NSMutableURLRequest autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x24bd 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:05.877 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e08e80 of class NSURL autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x2c3891 0x24eb 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:05.878 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e099b0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x37e6d4 0x30a6a9 0x25ca 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:05.880 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e0a9a0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x382b13 0x37e6f0 0x30a6a9 0x25ca 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:05.881 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e0ab30 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x37e726 0x30a6a9 0x25ca 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:05.882 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e0ab50 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x2df953 0x37e742 0x30a6a9 0x25ca 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:05.884 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e0bd20 of class NSThread autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x2893d4 0x2df65e 0x946ab89e 0x2e06f5 0x2f0411 0x2f02b3 0x2f0237 0x946ab89e 0x2f01e5 0x37e79c 0x30a6a9 0x25ca 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:05.892 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e0fb10 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x2df6b0 0x946ab89e 0x2e06f5 0x2f0411 0x2f02b3 0x2f0237 0x946ab89e 0x2f01e5 0x37e79c 0x30a6a9 0x25ca 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:06.228 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e10b90 of class NSHTTPURLResponse autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x30a72f 0x25ca 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:06.228 projectx[6357:20b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3e0ff40 of class NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x3226af 0x283e52 0x30a7a3 0x25ca 0x238a)
2010-03-12 00:03:06.229 projectx[6357:20b] <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
Welcome Test!<br />
Your location is  Germany .
</body>
```

it seems work, and then i create a simple php to read the post data and insert them into mysql:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br />
Your location is  <?php echo $_POST["location"]; ?> .
<?php $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$FirstName =$_POST["fname"]; 
$location =$_POST["location"];

mysql_select_db("test", $con); //what is your database name, 
//Create a table call persons, or u can use any table 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_db (firstName, location) 
VALUES ($FirstName,$location)");


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

but the page does not display my post variables. and it is not insert to mysql as well. Any ideas? thank u

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your errors is that you're trying to autorelease objects before you've created an autorelease pool.

It looks like you've placed your code in the main.c file. With iPhone apps you don't want to do this, you want to place your code into the main App delegate class and your created classes. 
I would suggest making a Hello World app first before trying something more complicated:

http://www.tuaw.com/2009/04/27/iphone-dev-101-the-hello-world-app/